# how to concate the jquery clone object to string

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

i have select2 box cloned and now i want to concatenate the cloned object with string and then append it to target field.
the html is

```
<select data-placeholder="Select a billable item" name="nvoice_billable_ITEMID" id="invoice_billable_ITEMID" class="invoice_billable_ITEMID">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="35089">Initial</option>
    <option value="35088">Standard</option>
</select>
```

i use code to initialize the select js code.

```
 var select_billable;
$(document).ready(function() {
    select_billable = $('.invoice_billable_ITEMID').clone();
    $(".nvoice_billable_ITEMID").select2({
        allowClear: true
    });});
```

on the function call add_fields i create the clone object and after concatenating it with string append it to target element. the clone object is created well but after append the string is showing `[object Object]`in the place of cloned object with in sting . how can i concatenate the object with string so that the select box is visible ??

```
//on call add the field for item
function add_fields(item_type){
    if(item_type == "Billable"){
        //   create the clone of select2 box
        var newBillableSelect = select_billable.clone();
        //function for concate the select2 box with string and append it
        appendRow(newBillableSelect);
        //initilizing the new select2 box
        newBillableSelect.select2();   
    }else if(item_type == "Product"){
        var newProductSelect = select_product.clone();
        appendRow(newProductSelect);
        newProductSelect.select2();  
    }
}
function appendRow(selectBox){
    var tr = '<tr class="fields_group" id="fields_group_ITEMID">'+
        '<td>'+ selectBox.html() +'</td>'+
        '<td>$<input type="text" style="width: 60px" size="30" name="unit_price[]" id="unit_price"></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" style="width: 45px" size="30" name="quantity[]" id="quantity"></td>'+
        '<td><input type="hidden" name="tax_id" id="tax_id"><label class="tax_name">N/A</label><input type="hidden" name="tax_rate[]" id="tax_rate"></td>'+
        '<td>$<input type="text" value="0.00" size="10" readonly="readonly" name="net_price" id="net_price" class="read_only_text right_align_text" style="background-color: #fff;border:none;width: 100px;box-shadow:none "></td>'+
        '<td><input type="hidden" value="false" name="net_price[]" id="net_price"><a tabindex="-1" onclick="remove_invoice_item_fields(this); return false;" href="#" class="link_red link_small">remove</a></td>'+
        '</tr>';
    $('#items_tbody').append(tr);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you had the `html()` part when you tested? I can't think of a scenario in which this method would return an object. Also, what is the `$('.invoice_billable_ITEMID')` selector matching? If it's matching a *select* element, then calling `html()` on it will return the nested *option* elements, which won't be valid html inside a *td*.

Comment: i have edit the post $('.invoice_billable_ITEMID') selecter is for select2.

Comment: i have edit the post for $('.invoice_billable_ITEMID') selector. it is for select2 box. and also you are correct it have no html() part but i just put it to try to get the object html but it only printing the options values of select box .

Comment: any idea of how to append object/cloned object into a string??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, you're getting close. The `.html()` method will return a string of the html, except that it will return the *inner* html of the element (i.e. the element's content/children). In order to get the html for the element itself, you could either wrap your select within a div and match that div with your jQuery selector, or you could do it with a temporary element, such as:

```
'<td>'+ $('<div>').append(selectBox).html() +'</td>'
```

Comment: nice solution. append to div, and grab innerHTML, on the fly. Thanks.